# IdentityServer4 and OidcClient on IOS prompt

Tags: identityserver4, identitymodel

I have IDS4 and a Xamarin.Forms app all working fine except one little issue.  Every single time the iOS app accesses the IDP server it first gives me this prompt:

"AppName" Wants to Use "" to Sign In
This allows the app and website to share information about you

What is causing this?

[image]

Comment: do you provide http:// or https:// url?

Answer (score 2):

I have this error using IdentityModel.OidcClient2.  Please see [this link](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/177) for the cause.  This is the gist of it:

### Cause

This is a system dialog that was added in iOS 11 to `SFAuthenticationSession`. It is triggered by this code in AppAuth:

```
SFAuthenticationSession* authenticationVC = 
 [[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL 
                            callbackURLScheme:redirectScheme 
                            completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable callbackURL, 
                                                NSError * _Nullable error) {
```

There isn't a way to get rid of the dialog, except to not use `SFAuthenticationSession` which means you lose Single SignOn, which is worse.

I ended up using SFSafariViewController instead of SFAuthenticationSession by using the method mentioned by MLeech [HERE](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2/issues/60#issuecomment-384891574)

### Solution

Which basically meant add these lines to your AppDelegate.cs

```
 public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static Action<string> CallbackHandler { get; set; }

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        CallbackHandler(url.AbsoluteString);
        CallbackHandler = null;

        return true;
    }
```

Then use this code for your SFAuthenticationSessionBrowser.cs

```
public class SFAuthenticationSessionBrowser : IBrowser
{
    public Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options)
    {
        var task = new TaskCompletionSource<BrowserResult>();

        var safari = new SFSafariViewController(new NSUrl(options.StartUrl));

        AppDelegate.CallbackHandler = async url =>
        {
            await safari.DismissViewControllerAsync(true);
            task.SetResult(new BrowserResult()
            {
                Response = url
            });
        };

        // https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24689/how-to-acces-the-current-view-uiviewcontroller-from-an-external-service
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }
        vc.PresentViewController(safari, true, null);

        return task.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to open the OIDC client in the app or are you redirect to an External Browser?

Comment: @johnny5 The OIDC client is initiated within the Xamarin Forms app then It launches the IDP servers's MVC login page through the iOS's browser, not sure which one. After a successful login to the IDP server you are redirected back to the app through a registered scheme name.   ....that is my understanding anyway.

Comment: Isnt that by design, if you were redirected in the app you wouldn't be able to validate that the idp is not a phishing site

Comment: @johnny5 The issue is fixed now so I'm not worried about it.  The resolution I provided is listed above.  If there is a problem with the resolution please let me know.